# searching and retrieving data using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search

I was wondering is node.js good fit for searching massive amount of data, i know its main use is for asynchronous sceanrious like chat, ftp and real time etc. I was thinking of using node.js with mongodb to search 300,000 records of books for the library at my university, and see if it would oppose to using php & mysql. any advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js would be a fine application interface for searching data .. but practically, so would PHP or many other languages :).

Your backend data storage solution (MySQL, MongoDB, ..) is a harder choice and really depends on the how you want to index and search the data.

If your main goal is search you probably want to look into a search application based on something like [Apache Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene).  These typically use a relational database backend, although some newer efforts like [ElasticSearch](http://elasticsearch.org) do have growing community support for ingesting data from sources like MongoDB (ref: [MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/)).

Since you mentioned book search and libraries, you might also want to look into [ILS (Integrated Library Search)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_library_system) applications which may already solve that problem.  There are several open source products such as [Koha](http://www.koha.org/) and [Evergreen](http://open-ils.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at MongooseJS
Absolute perfect fit in my opinion.